# Use PhoneGap + HTML5 and an Embedded Flash Movie

Tags: android, ios, flash, html, cordova

I wanted to know if it is possible to do the following:

1. Build a mobile app using HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript
2. Embed a Flash game (SWF) on one of the pages of the application
3. Wrap with PhoneGap, and deploy on Android an iOS
4. Keep the Flash game's functionality

I am considering doing this for an upcoming mobile project, and considering my options.  I can build in all Flash, or I can build using HTML5 and just embed the Flash on one page.  HTML5 would be much faster and cost-effective, and could accomplish what I need for the app's UI and everything else.  The thing is that I need to incorporate this Flash game into the site.  Will that mean that I have to build the entire application in Flash in order to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you the last person on Earth to hear that Flash doesn't work on iOS?

Well, I have news for you: Flash doesn't work on iOS ;-)

You can use Adobe's CS5 tools to compile your Flash game as a native iOS app (which is probably your best bet if you're determined to go the Flash route) but you can't display a SWF on an iPhone, regardless of how it is embedded.

Embedding the SWF using PhoneGap may be a semi-viable solution on Android (at least for some handset models), but the performance is unlikely to be that great, and since Adobe have officially abandoned Flash on the mobile, making Flash games for Android is not a very future-proof strategy at this point.

You'd be better off trying to create your game using a pure HTML5 game development library such as [ImpactJS](http://impactjs.com/) - the tools are not quite as rich as what you get with Adobe, but the cross-platform support and future outlook is much better.

Here's a nice table of different cross-platform JS game engine solutions that somebody put together: https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines

Comment: OK, first of all, I am very much aware that Flash doesn't work, that's not what I am asking.

What I am saying is that I have the option to use Flash or HTML5 to build this app.  The issue is that there is a game that is involved here, that I think would be best executed building in Flash.  So I wanted to know if it was possible to package an embedded flash movie for use in a native app using PhoneGap, because I don't have any experience with that, or if I should build the entire app using Flash, and deploy natively.

Thanks for your quick reply though.  Time is a factor here as well.

Comment: It's not possible to deploy an SWF on iOS using PhoneGap or any other method. it is possible to build the entire app in Flash and cross-compile to iPhone using Adobe CS5, so if you want to use Flash that's your only option.

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks!  I think I'm going to go the Flash/Adobe Air route.

Answer (score 0):

For simple animations You can also convert flash to HTML 5 (with Abobe tools , form google html5 convert dosen't ) and than put it in web view any platform Windows Phone, Win store.....
html 5 will work even without cordoba or phone gap