# Flash error on ios app

Tags: ios, cordova, flash

I have implemented IVR calling functionality using phonegap.It works perfectly on android but not on ios.When I debug app i got the Flash not installed error.Can we add flash player externally for app.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is not supported on iOS. You can check these pages for more informations :

http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_and_Adobe_Flash_controversy

[Use PhoneGap + HTML5 and an Embedded Flash Movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005556/use-phonegap-html5-and-an-embedded-flash-movie/9006246#9006246)